# How can I apply a function to every other row in a series in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table with only one column. I want to apply a function that I wrote to every other row in the series. However, when I do that I get an error!

```
The table looks like this:        And I want to get this:
names                             names
bank account                      bank account|bank|account
1256864                           1256864
bank share                        bank share|bank|share
42,566                            42,566          
bank currency                     bank currency|bank|currency
Dollar                            Dollar
batch number                      batch number|batch|number
001444                            001444
...                                ...
```

Here is the code that I wrote:

```
import pandas as pd
import re


df = pd.read_table('list_a.tsv')

def sep_rows (text):
    sperated = '|'.join(re.split(r'\s+', text))
    return text+'|'+sperated

# this applies the function to ALL rows!
print(df['names'].apply(sep_rows))
# I tried to choose every other row
a = df.iloc[::2].apply(sep_rows)

print(a) # But I gen an error!
```

And I get this:

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Answer (score 3):

Your approach (with `re` and `apply`) is overcomplicated and slow. The following expression uses native Pandas vectorization and is much more efficient (it runs about 4 times faster).

```
evens = df['names'].iloc[::2]    
evens[:] = evens + '|' + evens.str.replace('\s+', '|')
#                       names
#0  bank account|bank|account
#1                    1256864
#2      bank share|bank|share
#3                     42,566
```

Answer (score 1):

Treat text as a series, and then your function should work :

```
def sep_rows(text):
    separated = text.str.replace(r"\s+", "|")
    return text + "|" + separated

df.iloc[::2].apply(sep_rows)

             names
0   bank account|bank|account
2   bank share|bank|share
4   bank currency|bank|currency
6   batch number|batch|number
```

Another way to get your result is `list comprehension` :

```
import re
df['new_column'] = ["|".join((text, re.sub(r"\s+", "|", text))) 
                    if num%2 ==0 else text 
                    for num, text in enumerate(df.names)
                   ]

df

   names                  new_column
0   bank account    bank account|bank|account
1   1256864                          1256864
2   bank share      bank share|bank|share
3   42,566                           42,566
4   bank currency   bank currency|bank|currency
5   Dollar                           Dollar
6   batch number    batch number|batch|number
7   001444                           001444
```

Comment: The second method with list comprehension actually works. I also need the rows with odd index number to be embedded. Thank you.